# Populating the dropdown with the data on the SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

In my php application i have a dropdown which has to be populated with the data in the food_list table (item name).
so I have these code blocks.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <select name="item_name" class="form-control">
    <option> -- select food item --</option>
     <?php
        $ba = $b->get_all();
        foreach($ba as $item){

            echo "<option>$item->item_name</option>";
        }

    ?>
   </select>
```

And in my class I've the get_all function as follows.

```
function get_all(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM food_list";
    $ref = $this->db->query($sql);
    while($row=$ref->fetch_array()){
        $b=new foodlist();
        $b->item_name=$row['item_name'];
        $b->unit_price=$row['unit_price'];


        $ar[]=$b;
    }
    return $ar;
}
```

What can be the reason for not getting the dropdown populated with the relevant data.
Note: Database Connection is working properly

**food_list(foodID,f_name,f_price)**

The data should come from the food_list table f_name column.
Please be kind enough to help me.
Thank you

Comment: so what problem you are facing?

Comment: What's behind `$this->db->query($sql);` can you please provide the entire class?

Comment: @AlivetoDie the dropdown is not getting populated with the data in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get multiple values with [`mysqli_result::fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) you nedd to put this into a while-loop:

```
function get_all(){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM food_list";
     $ref = $this->db->query($sql);

     while ($row = $ref->fetch_array()) {
          $ar[] = $row;
     }

     return $ar;
}
```

This will return an array like this:

```
Array (
     Array (
          [item_name] => Item 1 name
          [unit_price] => 15.00
     )
     Array (
          [item_name] => Item 2 name
          [unit_price] => 20.00
     )
)
```

Comment: tis is correct answer.+1. just add how he is going to use it in option values and name part.